# localScroll is working in Firefox, Safari, but not Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scrollto

I've added scrollTo & localScroll to a single-page site. It was working but suddenly is not. I've reverted much of the HTML/CSS/JS changes I've made and tried every version other posts have thrown out there, but to no avail.

It works great in Firefox & Safari, (hell, even Canary!) but not in Chrome... I wonder if there was something in a nightly that screwed it up... here's the code

```
<nav class="top-nav">
    <button class="menu-toggle">&nbsp;</button>
    <ul class="collapse-menu" id="navigation">
        <li><a class="scrollTo" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="scrollTo" href="#participate">Participate</a></li>
        <li class="spacer"></li>
        <li><a class="scrollTo" href="#awards">Awards</a></li>
        <li><a class="scrollTo" href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and targets look like this

```
<section id="about" class="gold">
  ...
</section>
```

using JQuery 1.10.2